# Extract information from closest timestamp in separate dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, date-comparison

I have two dataframes, one is a continuous data(taken every 15 seconds) from a buoy in a fixed location and the other is observation data taken at many different time intervals in different places. Both have consistent timestamps in their respective dataframes. For every observation I need to take the timestamp of the observation and find the closest timestamp in the continuous dataframe, extract information from that row, and add it to the observation. I am having a hard time finding a way to find the closest timestamp in the continuous data with my series.

Observation data:

```
   counter    depth  latdeg   latmin     latdec  londeg  lonmin    ts
0      100001   21.110      72  18.5412  72.309020    -148 -47.071 2018-03-20 17:21:49+01:00
1      100002   22.140      72  18.5448  72.309080    -148 -47.0785 2018-03-20 17:22:07+01:00
2      100003   45.300      72  18.5396  72.308993    -148 -47.0936 2018-03-20 17:34:38+01:00
3      100004   45.310      72  18.5360  72.308933    -148 -47.0974 2018-03-20 17:36:31+01:00
```

Continuous data:

```
    sec sat lat long    alt time
4164    62460   9   72.31061472 -148.790606 -6.9809 2018-03-20 17:21:00+01:00
4165    62475   9   72.31061655 -148.7906147    -7.0923 2018-03-20 17:21:15+01:00
4166    62490   9   72.31061099 -148.7906154    -7.7008 2018-03-20 17:21:30+01:00
4167    62505   9   72.31060295 -148.7906237    -8.3746 2018-03-20 17:21:45+01:00
4168    62520   9   72.31059877 -148.7906251    -7.5989 2018-03-20 17:22:00+01:00
```

so for example I would like to take `obs[0]['ts']` and find the index of the closest time in `cont['time']`, which would be `4167`, to then append the lat long and alt to the observation dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **[pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)**

It allows you to join two DataFrames on keys that are not exact. In this case, you want to use it with `direciton = nearest` to match based on the two closest timestamps.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge_asof(df_obs, df_cont[['lat', 'long', 'alt', 'time']], 
              left_on='ts', right_on='time', direction='nearest')
```

Outputs:

```
   counter  depth  latdeg   latmin     latdec  londeg   lonmin                  ts        lat        long     alt                time
0   100001  21.11      72  18.5412  72.309020    -148 -47.0710 2018-03-20 16:21:49  72.310603 -148.790624 -8.3746 2018-03-20 16:21:45
1   100002  22.14      72  18.5448  72.309080    -148 -47.0785 2018-03-20 16:22:07  72.310599 -148.790625 -7.5989 2018-03-20 16:22:00
2   100003  45.30      72  18.5396  72.308993    -148 -47.0936 2018-03-20 16:34:38  72.310599 -148.790625 -7.5989 2018-03-20 16:22:00
3   100004  45.31      72  18.5360  72.308933    -148 -47.0974 2018-03-20 16:36:31  72.310599 -148.790625 -7.5989 2018-03-20 16:22:00
```

You can then drop the `time` column if you don't want it, I just left it in to make it clear how the merge worked.

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: left keys must be sorted" , which they are and after rooting around it seems like that would happen if there were any NaN values in the timestamp, but my dataframes do not have any. Do you have any idea about that error? Thank you, this is definitely a better approach then what I was trying before.

Comment: @PatriciaNelsen  Sorry for the late response! Yeah the one caveat of merge is that you need to first sort the keys you are merging on, otherwise it wont work.